# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: and cannot find the reason

Tags: c++, class, build

I have my main.cc, which is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sally.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
   Sally sallyObject;
   sallyObject.printCrap();

}
```

and header file, Sally.h, which is

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H

class Sally{
public:
    Sally();
    void printCrap();
protected:
private:
};

#endif //BURRITO_H
```

and Sally.cc, which is

```
#include "Sally.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Sally::Sally()
{
}

void Sally::printCrap(){
    cout << "did someone say steak?" << endl;
}
```

and those three files are located in same directory.
When I type `g++ main.cc`, I cannot build the code. It says

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "Sally::printCrap()", referenced from:
         _main in main-16cd07.o
    "Sally::Sally()", referenced from:
         _main in main-16cd07.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to compile all the .cc files together, because sally.cc isn’t being included.

`g++ main.cc sally.cc`

Should do the trick.

Including the dot-h file makes the definition of your class visible to all (including main.cc) but the actual body of the code is not seen without it being compiled.